# Как правильно передать ID

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть 2 файла:

Содержимое **ProductAdmin.php**

```
if(is_array($razmers)){ 
    $razmers_ids = array();
    foreach($razmers as $razmer){
        if(!empty($razmer->id))
        $this->razmers->update_razmer($razmer->id, $razmer);
        else{
            $razmer->product_id = $product->id;
            $razmer->id = $this->razmers->add_razmer($razmer);
        }
        $razmer = $this->razmers->get_razmer($razmer->id);
        if(!empty($razmer->id))
        $razmers_ids[] = $razmer->id;
    }
    // Удалить вариант
    $current_razmers = $this->razmers->get_razmer(array('product_id'=>$product->id));
    foreach($current_razmers as $current_razmer)
        if(!in_array($current_razmer->id, $razmers_ids))
        $this->razmers->delete_razmer($current_razmer->id);
}
```

Содержимое **Razmers.php**

```
public function delete_razmer($id)
    {
        if(!empty($id))
        {
            $query = $this->db->placehold("DELETE FROM __razmers WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1", intval($id));
            $this->db->query($query);
        }
    }
```

При нажатии на кнопку удалить ID строки должен идти сюда `WHERE id = ?`и соответственно должна удалятся строка из БД, но при нажатии строка не удаляется, уже неделю пробую, гуглю и все никак не понимаю, в чем причина и как решить. Буду признателен вас за помощь и ваше время!

Comment: а `$id` в `delete_razmer` приходит ?

Comment: @Alex нет, в этом и есть проблема.